# TextureVideoView crashes because of MediaPlayer - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I' m trying to develop an app which will work with videos. At first i' ve tried the standard VideoView but it flickers and not efficient. So i' ve searched and found TextureVideoView implementation but i got this error message;

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.media.MediaPlayer
        at            
    com.challenge.papilio.TextureVideoView.initPlayer(TextureVideoView.java:155)
```

Here is the code at TextureVideoView.java:155;

```
    private void initPlayer() {
    if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); //Here it crashes
    } else {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
    }
    mIsVideoPrepared = false;
    mIsPlayCalled = false;
    mState = State.UNINITIALIZED;
}
```

And also i have to mention that, i' m using this view for 6-7 videos (all the same source) in the first two video there is nothing wrong but the others wont show up because of this media player crash.

I' ve searched for solution but nothing came up. All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please provide the code that's throwing this error.

Comment: I've edited as you wish.